# How to restrict JButton to change it's dimensions as a result of revalidation

Tags: java, swing, resize, runtime, jbutton

I have a panel (with GridLayout(**0,1**)) embedded on JFrame.

As per my requirement :-

- I am adding (JButton,JTextArea) in pairs on above declared panel.
- Now, on click of JButton of any pair, it's JTextArea should be removed, and on reclicking JButton, it's JTextArea should be added again.

Everything is working fine, except below two listed problems :

1. Dimensions of JButton are changed on revalidation.
2. Initial dimensions of JButton are very large(How to restrict dimension of JButton)

For reference, have a look at this [image: screenshot].

And Please find below modified Code listings :-

TestFrame.java

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    final JPanel panel ;

    private TestFrame() {
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) ;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) ;
        panel = new JPanel() ;
        panel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 1) ) ;

        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; ++i){
            TButton btn = new TButton("User " + i + " [Toggle Button for TextArea " + i + "] (Click)")  ;
            panel.add(btn) ;        btn.addActionListener(this) ;   panel.add(new JScrollPane(btn.getLoggingArea())) ;
        }

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER) ;
        setVisible(true) ;
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TButton btn = (TButton) e.getSource() ;
        JPanel parent = (JPanel) btn.getParent() ;

        int index = getIndex(parent, btn) ;

        if(btn.isLoggingAreaVisible()){
            parent.remove( parent.getComponent(index + 1) ) ;
            btn.setLoggingAreaVisible(false) ;
        }else{
            parent.add(new JScrollPane(btn.getLoggingArea()), index + 1) ;
            btn.setLoggingAreaVisible(true) ;
        }

        parent.revalidate() ;
        parent.repaint() ;
    }

    private int getIndex(JComponent parent, Component btn) {

        Component []comps = parent.getComponents() ;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < comps.length ; ++i){
            if( comps[i].equals(btn) ){
                return i ;
            }
        }

        return -1 ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame() ;
    }
}
```

TButton.java

```
package com.test;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TButton extends JButton{

    private JTextArea loggingArea ;
    private boolean loggingAreaVisible = true ;

    public TButton(String threadName) {
        super(threadName) ;
        initComponents(threadName) ;
    }

    public void initComponents(String threadName) {

        String str = "1. By default large buttons are displayed." + "\n" +
                     "    But, I want buttons with a little small dimensions." + "\n\n" +
                     "2. On click of above button, above button expands to cover space used by this textArea." + "\n" +
                     "    But, what I want, that button size does not changes onClick, only textArea length increases/decreases." ;
        loggingArea = new JTextArea(getText() + " textArea." + "\n\n" + str + "\n\n" + "Type Here...") ;
    }


    public boolean isLoggingAreaVisible() {
        return loggingAreaVisible;
    }

    public void setLoggingAreaVisible(boolean loggingAreaVisible) {
        this.loggingAreaVisible = loggingAreaVisible;
    }

    public JTextArea getLoggingArea() {
        return loggingArea;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Rits :)

Comment: +1 I once used your avatar as my desktop background. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use e.g. vertical BoxLayout instead of GridLayout

Comment: searched on net for "java vertical BoxLayout example", and voilla..., it worked like charm. accepting your answer... :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Return `JPanel` (`BorderLayout`) nested

   - `JPanel` (has by default `FlowLayout`) for `JButton`, this `JPanel` put to the `BorderLayout.NORTH`
   - `JTextArea` put to then `BorderLayout.CENTER`
2. There I can't see reason for `revalidate & repaint`, only in the case that you switch between `JComponents` or remove and then add new `JComponent(s)`,
3. For `hide/visible` particular `JPanel` or `JComponent` use method `setVisible()`

Comment: Thnks for your inputs. I tried this approach, but setVisible(false), leaves an empty space, which is not my requirement. As per requirement, this empty space should be used by other textAreas.

Comment: +1  Consider also a `JToolBar` (instead of the `JPanel` with `FlowLayout`) for the `JButton` in the `NORTH` constraint.

Comment: @Andrew : jtoolbar.add(btn, JToolBar.NORTH) throws illegal component position. jtoolbar.add(btn) works fine, but displays [JButton,JTextArea] in left right position.

Answer (score 1):

You should use another layout. [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) draws the components to maximum size available.

Comment: @rits Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html